# Database: how to get multiple values from two tables having one common column

Tags: sql, database, wso2, h2

I have two two tables:

Table #1: columns

```
Producer   ConsumerKey    time                resourcepath    Day
------------------------------------------------------------------
test           7890       2018-09-25 09:44     /12345         23
dev            5678       2018-09-25 09:10     /abcv          26
```

Table #2 : columns

```
ConsumerName    ConsumerKey    Day
-----------------------------------
admin              7890        23
dummy              5678        26
```

I need to query the tables in such way that I should get the distinct value from table 1 and corresponding consumername from table 2 for a specific date

So the final result should look like:

```
Producer    ConsumerKey   time                resourcepath   ConsumerName   Day
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test            7890      2018-09-25 09:44    /12345         admin          23
dev             5678      2018-09-25 09:10    /abcv          dummy          26
```

Is there any way to get this. Any help please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic join should work.

```
SELECT t1.producer,
       t1.consumerkey,
       t1.time,
       t1.resourcepath,
       t2.consumername,
       t1.day
       FROM table1 t1
            INNER JOIN table2 t2
                       ON t2.consumerkey = t1.consumerkey
                          AND t2.day = t1.day;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: But how could this is possible to search for a given date?

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause like `WHERE t1.time = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.Producer, table1.ConsumerKey, table1.Time, table1.resourcepath, table1.day, table2.ConsumerName 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.ConsumerKey = table2.ConsumerKey 
AND table1.time = "<ENTER YOUR TIME HERE>"
```

This will work fine to get the following details.